# Session is not defined sailsjs

Tags: node.js, session, sails.js, policies

I'm writing a policy checkSession which basically destroy session after some time.

`checkSession.js (policies/checksession.js)`

```
var moment = require('moment');

function checkLastActivity(req) {
    if (!req.session.lastActivity) {
        return false; // no session.
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

function setActivity(req) {
    req.session.lastActivity = moment(new Date()).format();
    return true;
}

function updateActivity(req, res, updated) {
    req.session.lastActivity = moment(new Date()).format();
    updated(null, {
        isdestroted: 0
    });
}

function checkIdleTime(req, idleTime) {
    try {
        var lastActivityTime = moment(req.session.lastActivity).format();
        var currentActivityTime = moment(new Date()).format();
        timeIdle = moment.utc(moment(currentActivityTime).diff(moment(lastActivityTime))).format("HH:mm:ss");
        minutestimeIdle = moment.duration(timeIdle).asMinutes().toFixed(2);
        idleTime(null, minutestimeIdle);
    } catch (e) {
        idleTime(e, null);
    }
}

function destroyActivity(req, res, destroyed) {
  try {
    req.session.destroy();
    sails.log.info("***********************session is expired for user *****************");
    destroyed(null, {
        isdestroted: 1,
        redirectCode: 200,
        redirectView: '/login/'
    });
  } catch(e) {
    destroyed(e, null);
  }
}

module.exports = function isSession(req, res, next) {
    cleanParamsService.cleanPrm(req);
    async.waterfall([
        function(callback) {
            callback(null, checkLastActivity(req));
        },
        function(isLastActivity, callback) {
            if (isLastActivity) {
                checkIdleTime(req, function(err, timeIdle) {
                    if (minutestimeIdle > sails.config.session_timeout) { /*if user is being idle*/
                        destroyActivity(req, res, function(err, destroyed) {
                            sails.log.warn('User was idle since' + minutestimeIdle + ', sessions are destroyed');
                            callback(null, destroyed);
                        })
                    } else {
                        updateActivity(req, res, function(err, updated) {
                            callback(null, updated);
                        });
                    }
                })
            } else {
                updateActivity(req, res, function(err, updated) {
                    callback(null, updated);
                });
            }
        }
    ], function(err, result) {
        if (result) {
            if (result.isdestroted == 0) {
                return next();
            } else {
                return res.redirect(result.redirectCode, result.redirectView);
            }
        } else {
            sails.log.error('err:', err);
            return res.badRequest();
        }
    });
};
```

now if i change it to

```
var moment = require('moment');

function checkLastActivity(req) {
    if (!req.session.lastActivity) {
        return false; // no session.
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

function setActivity(req) {
    req.session.lastActivity = moment(new Date()).format();
    return true;
}

function updateActivity(req, res, updated) {
    req.session.lastActivity = moment(new Date()).format();
    updated(null, {
        isdestroted: 0
    });
}

function checkIdleTime(req, idleTime) {
    try {
        var lastActivityTime = moment(req.session.lastActivity).format();
        var currentActivityTime = moment(new Date()).format();
        timeIdle = moment.utc(moment(currentActivityTime).diff(moment(lastActivityTime))).format("HH:mm:ss");
        minutestimeIdle = moment.duration(timeIdle).asMinutes().toFixed(2);
        idleTime(null, minutestimeIdle);
    } catch (e) {
        idleTime(e, null);
    }
}

function destroyActivity(req, res, destroyed) {
    try {
        req.session.destroy();
        sails.log.info("***********************session is expired for user *****************");
        destroyed(null, {
            isdestroted: 1,
            redirectCode: 200,
            redirectView: '/login/'
        });
    } catch (e) {
        destroyed(e, null);
    }
}

module.exports = function isSession(req, res, next) {
    cleanParamsService.cleanPrm(req);
    async.waterfall([
        function(callback) {
            callback(null, checkLastActivity(req));
        },
        function(isLastActivity, callback) {
            if (isLastActivity) {
                checkIdleTime(req, function(err, timeIdle) {
                    if (minutestimeIdle > sails.config.session_timeout) { /*if user is being idle*/
                        destroyActivity(req, res, function(err, destroyed) {
                            sails.log.warn('User was idle since' + minutestimeIdle + ', sessions are destroyed');
                            callback(null, destroyed);
                        })
                    } else {
                        updateActivity(req, res, function(err, updated) {
                            callback(null, updated);
                        });
                    }
                })
            } else {
                updateActivity(req, res, function(err, updated) {
                    callback(null, updated);
                });
            }
        },
        function(resp, callback) {
            if (resp.isdestroted == 0) {
                req.fresh;
                req.session.isdestroted = false;
                callback(null, resp);
            } else {
                req.fresh;
                req.session.isdestroted = true;
                callback(null, resp);
            }
        }
    ], function(err, result) {
        if (result) {
            if (result.isdestroted == 0) {
                return next();
            } else {
                return res.redirect(result.redirectCode, result.redirectView);
            }
        } else {
            sails.log.error('err:', err);
            return res.badRequest();
        }
    });
};
```

The application trigger error where i'm setting req.session.isdestroted = true/false and the error is

```
warn: User was idle since0.38, sessions are destroyed
debug: Lowering sails...
C:\Users\Vbase002\Desktop\CC\Website\api\policies\checkSession.js:83
                req.session.isdestroted = true;
                                        ^
TypeError: Cannot set property 'isdestroted' of undefined
    at C:\Users\Vbase002\Desktop\CC\Website\api\policies\checkSession.js:83:41
    at fn (C:\Users\Vbase002\Desktop\CC\Website\node_modules\sails\node_modules\
async\lib\async.js:579:34)
    at Immediate._onImmediate (C:\Users\Vbase002\Desktop\CC\Website\node_modules
\sails\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:495:34)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:367:17)
```

i'm setting this session to show some message on login page to user, but i don't know why sails is behaving like this.

is there any way to handle this scenario and also please let me know the reason why this is happening.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [behavior from express](https://github.com/expressjs/session#user-content-sessiondestroy).

> **Session.destroy()**
>
> Destroys the session, removing req.session, will be re-generated next
>   request.

As your *warn* log indicates, `req.session.destroy();` has been called before the error.

You could use [`req.session.regenerate()`](https://github.com/expressjs/session#user-content-sessionregenerate) to have the expected behavior.

> **Session.regenerate()**
>
> To regenerate the session simply invoke the method, once complete a
>   new SID and Session instance will be initialized at req.session.